# Importing modules from different subdirectory (w/ multiple folders and subdirectories)

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following file structure :

```
Orbital folder: 

    ESG folder:
         SUSA folder: 
              SUSA.ipynb

    modules folder:
         orbital.py
         __init__.py
         orbital.ipynb   #convert this to orbital.py
```

I want to import orbital.py into SUSA.ipynb but I've had no success. I've looked into documentation and other similar questions on here.

A couple I've tried:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/thomasmac/Desktop/Orbital/modules/orbital")

sys.path.append("/Users/thomasmac/Desktop/Orbital/modules/orbital")

from modules import orbital
```

or just:

```
import orbital
```

But each time it returns an error of, no module named modules or orbital

Comment: Suggest using relative paths imports in all your modules with dependencies. For example if you want to import the "libs" folder one level above, you would do     sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), os.path.pardir, 'libs')).     That will cause your import to work regardless where you call your pyfile from as long as the "libs" folder (used as an example) exists in the parent directory of the folder containing your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/thomasmac/Desktop/Orbital")
from modules import orbital
```

Comment: I get [NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern u'orbital.ipynb' matched no files
This application is used to convert notebook files (*.ipynb) to various other
formats.

Comment: Apparently, this warning doesn't come directly from your import statement. You need to find out which statement causes the warning. It may be in the `modules` or `orbital` modules, or other modules imported from here.